# Why will Ubuntu 12.04 boot but not install?

Tags: installation, boot-failure, bootloader

I can boot the disk but when it gives me the 5 options
-Try Ubuntu without installing
-Install Ubuntu
-Check disk for defects
-Test memory
-Boot from first hard disk
I select the "Install Ubuntu"option then it just restarts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried "Check disk for defects"?

Comment: yes but it restarts

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably corrupt. Maybe something happened when downloading. You could re-download the image and make a new disk. You could also check the md5 checksum located in the iso file. You can downlaod simple programs that check the md5 for you

Comment: where are the md5 files?

Comment: @Jean: In the ISO root, there is a MD5SUMS file. Try `md5sum -c MD5SUMS`.